# A table with all attributes making the primary key

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have two tables: `Student` and `Shop` and I would like to record information about which student visited which shop and if the number of visits is above `n`, they should received a discount:

This is how I did it:

[image]

All of attributes (`studentID, shopID, time, date`) in table `StudentShop` makes the primary key for this table. I just wanted to know if this design is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **relation between entieties Student - Shop** is **many to many** relationship,
it is always implemented using **associative table** (consists of primary keys from both relations), so StudentShop table - is **good choice** for implementation of such relation.

Comment: Thanks. One question: I have a attribute in Student called `discount` which is calculated using `StudentShop` relation. Should I included in Student or it can be calculated using a query?

Comment: Discount can be updated, as number of shops visited by a student increases. In case if you include it in student you should consider updating of rows to maintain actual state of each student data, if you use a query for it`s calculation you don`t need to track whether students data need to be updated - you always get valid data for each student